# Print non ASCII characters as their hex in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

How do I print a string in PHP in which all the non-ASCII characters gets converted to their HEX value (eg. 0x02) and displayed?
I want users to know that they are entering non-ASCII values. I don't want to strip them. Instead, I would like to display it so that they can edit and correct the mistakes.

I want to allow users to enter standard tab, new lines, etc (maybe upto ASCII 127).

I tried `quoted_printable_encode()` but it displays `=` as `=3D`. 
Other non-ASCII characters as `=[HEXVAL]`. The equal sign creates confusion.

I tried `preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $string)` but it ended up removing tabs, new lines, etc.

Comment: Can you post an example string and the expected output? (Also include what you've tried so far.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to acheive when it comes to unicode characters. Even valid unicode characters (there are a ton of it) might not being printable because the current font contains no letter definitions for that character. Meaning a German unicode font might not contain all valid Chinese characters for example.

If you just care about ascii, you can use `ctype_print()` to check if a character is printable or not.

Example:

```
// test string contains printable and non printable characters
$string = "\x12\x12hello\x10world\x03";

$allowed = array("\x10", /* , ... */);

// iterate through string
for($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {

    // check if current char is printable
    if(ctype_print($string[$i]) || in_array($string[$i], $allowed)) {
        print $string[$i];
    } else {
        // use printf and ord to print the hex value if
        // it is a non printable character
        printf("\\x%02X", ord($string[$i]));
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
\x12\x12hello
world\x03
```

Comment: This [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php#109014) in ctype_print's doc says Tab, carriage returns are not detected as printable. But I need those to be displayed.

Comment: what about using a whitelist? I named it `$allowed`. Check my update

Answer (score 7):

```
substr(json_encode((string)$string), 1, -1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for malformed UTF-8, as `json_encode` will just return an empty string (or throw an exception, if you use `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`)